# Clustering with a lot of data

Tags: bigdata, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, dbscan

i need to cluster about 2 million data points, the dataframe consist in latitudes, longitudes and another variable. I've tried k-means with not so great results. I've also tried DBSCAN and MeanShift but with DBSCAN i got memory error and MeanShift takes about 3 days. Do you guys know any method or technique to make this more efficient?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN should take *linear* memory. That is as good as it gets.

Maybe you just need to choose a better implementation, or parameters.

The sklearn documentation discussing their problem:

> This implementation bulk-computes all neighborhood queries, which increases the memory complexity to O(n.d) where d is the average number of neighbors, while original DBSCAN had memory complexity O(n). It may attract a higher memory complexity when querying these nearest neighborhoods, depending on the algorithm.
>
> One way to avoid the query complexity is to pre-compute sparse neighborhoods in chunks using NearestNeighbors.radius_neighbors_graph with mode='distance', then using metric='precomputed' here.
>
> Another way to reduce memory and computation time is to remove (near-)duplicate points and use sample_weight instead.

Now the first workaround is even *wrong*. If there are on average d neighbors, materializing the radius_neighbors_graph will have O(n.d) entries, too. So this cannot be much better...

A textbook implementation of DBSCAN only needs O(n) memory. So for large data sets, the current sklearn implementation is not a good choice. Your best bet is to make the radius much smaller!

Hmmm... I remember a blog post from a few years ago that clustered some 10 million coordinates in like 10 minutes with DBSCAN. But I can't find it right now anymore.